# json SELECT multiple value by key in java

Tags: java, json

I have one json like below given

```
[{
    "D_Table_Name": "BUILDING",
    "S_Table_Name": "View1",
    "S_Data_Field_Name": "USECD",
    "D_Field_Name": "Description",
    "MappingCode": "FIELD"
  },
  {
    "D_Table_Name": "BUILDING",
    "S_Table_Name": "View1",
    "S_Data_Field_Name": "USECD",
    "D_Field_Name": "StndCode",
    "MappingCode": "FIELD"
  },
  {
    "D_Table_Name": "asdasd",
    "S_Table_Name": "View1",
    "S_Data_Field_Name": "qwew",
    "D_Field_Name": "ijhbgr4",
    "MappingCode": "FIELD"
  },
  {
    "D_Table_Name": "qwsdcv",
    "S_Table_Name": "View1",
    "S_Data_Field_Name": "kjmnbv",
    "D_Field_Name": "dszfs",
    "MappingCode": "FIELD"
  }]
```

how to get all value of the key `S_Table_Name`

Comment: What did you try so far? I'd use some kind of loop and probably an if-block or two. - To be serious: that question is quite vage, please elaborate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for values inside Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443379/how-to-search-for-values-inside-json-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using any particular library to convert JSON string into an Object, Let's say I am taking [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library

```
List<String> sTableNameValues = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String,String>> input = new GSON.fromJSON(inputJSONString);
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry: input.entrySet()){
   if(entry.getKey().equals("S_Table_Name")){
      sTableNameValues.add(entry.getValue());
   }
}
// Now all your S_Table_Name values are inside your list.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jackson library:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode array = mapper.readValue(yourJson, JsonNode.class);
```

Get values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
  String reportKey = array.get(i).get("S_Table_Name").textValue();
  System.out.println(reportKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like [json-path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) should be of help. In your case, the expression should be something like:

```
$[*].S_Table_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `org.json.JSONObject` library. Please see below code for this :

```
String response = "[{\"D_Table_Name\": \"BUILDING\",\"S_Table_Name\": \"View1\",\"S_Data_Field_Name\": \"USECD\",\"D_Field_Name\": \"Description\",\"MappingCode\": \"FIELD\"},{\"D_Table_Name\": \"BUILDING\",\"S_Table_Name\": \"View1\",\"S_Data_Field_Name\": \"USECD\",\"D_Field_Name\": \"StndCode\",\"MappingCode\": \"FIELD\"},{\"D_Table_Name\": \"asdasd\",\t\t\"S_Table_Name\": \"View1\",\"S_Data_Field_Name\": \"qwew\",\"D_Field_Name\": \"ijhbgr4\",\"MappingCode\": \"FIELD\"},{\"D_Table_Name\": \"qwsdcv\",\"S_Table_Name\": \"View1\",\t\"S_Data_Field_Name\": \"kjmnbv\",\"D_Field_Name\": \"dszfs\",\"MappingCode\": \"FIELD\"}]";

    JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray(response);

    if (responseArray.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject responseObject = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (responseObject.has("S_Table_Name")) {
                String S_Table_Name = responseObject.getString("S_Table_Name");
                System.out.println(S_Table_Name);
            }
        }
    }
```